# Rename a dynamically named directory in Ant?

Tags: ant

There are bunches of answers for how to rename a directory, but they all require knowing the exact directory name. In my case, the name is dynamically generated. I want to do something like this, but this fails since I can't wildcard the source directory:

```
<copy todir="./some/runtime/directory/mydir">
    <fileset dir="some/build/dir/mydir*"/> <!-- name is mydir_<timestamp> -->
</copy>
```

In bash, I could do `mv some/build/dir/mydir* some/runtime/dir/mydir`. I'm trying to find the equivalent ant command.

Answer (score 1):

If it would sufficient to copy the directory contents, then just clean your build folder, you can try this:

```
<copy todir="./some/runtime/directory/mydir">
    <fileset dir="some/build/dir">
        <include name="**/mydir*/**/*" /> <!-- or just mydir/**/* -->
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it copies the directory, so I get /some/runtime/directory/mydir/mydir_<timestamp>

Answer (score 1):

I created a property first and then copied that: -

```
<dirset id="my-dir-set" 
        dir="some/build/dir" includes="mydir*"/>
<property name="my-dir-name" refid="my-dir-set" />
<fail message="Must have exactly one directory - ${my-dir-name}">
    <condition>
        <resourcecount refid="my-dir-set" count="1" when="ne" />
    </condition>
</fail>
<move file="${my-dir-name}" 
      tofile="./some/runtime/directory/mydir" />
```

although, if you can guarantee the dirset is unique without the test: -

```
<move tofile="./some/runtime/directory/mydir">
    <dirset dir="some/build/dir" includes="mydir*" />
</move>
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbeled across the same problem. After no found answere worked as wanted, because always the dynamic directory name is also copied, i came to this solution:

```
<copy todir="some/runtime/directory/myTargetDir">
    <fileset dir="some/build/dir" includes="mySourceDir_*/**/*"/>
    <cutdirsmapper dirs="1"/>
</copy>
```

This copies the **included content** of "some/build/dir/mySourceDir_* " to "some/runtime/directory/myTargetDir". The "cutdirsmapper" does the trick, by stripping the dynamic directory name "mySourceDir_*".

(Tested with Ant 1.10.9.)